# NodeJS Mongoose relationship foreign keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Okay, so I'm trying out Mongoose to create some models.

My User model looks like this, and my Post model looks almost the same but with different fields. The question is, how do I create a relation between these two models? A User may have many Post and a Post may belong to a User.
That's what I quite don't understand since there is no foreign key like in MySQL.

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------.
|    Require modules                                              |
'-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------.
|    A model needs a scheme that starts with a                    |
|    constant that are named to define the scheme                 |
'-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
let userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 4, max: 16,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        min: 4,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    lastSeen: Date,
});

/*----------------------------------------------------------------.
|    Add timestamps                                               |
|    created_at                                                   |
|    updated_at                                                   |
'-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
userSchema.set('timestamps', true);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------.
|    Plugins!                                                     |
'-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
userSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-paginate'));

/*----------------------------------------------------------------.
|    Define the model                                             |
'-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
let User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Would it be the right way to put the following inside the User schema?

```
posts: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
}]
```

Or is this wrong?

Comment: I would recommend creating a user id field for every post, your way things get out of hand real fast when your scale grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right! Also, in order to populate the posts field when getting the users, you would need to add this:

```
this.find(query).populate('posts').exec();
```

Hope it helps!